# Proxying traffic on local unix to a remote unix socket over SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh, unix-sockets

I am trying to have a local Unix domain socket, say, `~/docker.sock`. I want it to proxy everything to a remote Unix domain socket running elsewhere over SSH. (You can find a diagram of what I’m trying to do below).

[OpenSSH supports this](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssh+unix+domain+socket+forwarding) ([an example](http://www.25thandclement.com/~william/projects/streamlocal.html) here). For instance, this command will proxy MySQL client connections on a remote server to my local instance:

```
ssh -R/var/run/mysql.sock:/var/run/mysql.sock -R127.0.0.1:3306:/var/run/mysql.sock somehost
```

But this is **not** how I want it to be like. It forwards the traffic that comes to the remote socket to my local socket (I want it the other way).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The man page for `ssh` offers two complementary options: `-R` for remote forwarding to local, and `-L` for local forwarding to remote.

In your case just use `-L` instead of `-R`.

Answer (score 1):

Create ssh tunnel from local (Mac/linux) host

```
ssh -nNT -L $(pwd)/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock user@someremote
```

export ENV variable

```
export DOCKER_HOST=$(pwd)/docker.sock
```

and use :)

from [here](https://medium.com/@dperny/forwarding-the-docker-socket-over-ssh-e6567cfab160)